# .htaccess rule not working with strange characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

For some reason I can't understand, the following Rewrite rule doesn't work. The ' character is OK if I set it beween () according to https://www.regextester.com/

If I check the rule with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ the URL I use for testing ([www.google.com/Articles/Rob'sRecommendations.html](http://www.google.com/Articles/Rob%27sRecommendations.html)) doesn't trigger the rule.

`RewriteRule ^/Articles/Rob(')sRecommendations.html /looking-for-something/ [L,NC,R=301]`

Any ideas?

Comment: It's too late for me to post an answer sorry but; try testing without the apostrophe in both the URL and `.htaccess` rule, and you'll get the same result - "This rule was not met."; the issue is not so simply the apostrophe. Also; ensure the `RewriteEngine` is `on` when testing, if madewithlove.be cares about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash in your rewrite rule is what appears to be causing the issue. Using https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test [https://www.google.com/Articles/Rob'sRecommendations.html](https://www.google.com/Articles/Rob%27sRecommendations.html) with the following .htaccess rule [works](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=cd504da7-4ba1-50ad-b6c3-b44bb2e94220).

```
RewriteRule ^/?Articles/Rob(')sRecommendations.html looking-for-something/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

In the above .htaccess rule, the original "/" is replaced with "/?"

Testing with the original slash completely removed also [appears to work](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=93da0ee4-2979-5f59-a91d-b43412c7a72a), but the following source explains why using "/?" is preferable and more versatile.

More info:

> The {REQUEST_URI} string starts with a / character. Apache changed
> regex engines when it changed versions, so Apache version 1 requires
> the leading slash while Apache 2 forbids it! We can satisfy both
> versions by making the leading slash optional with the expression ^/?
> (? is the metacharacter for zero or one of the preceding character).
> So now we have:

[Source](https://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/).

Comment: Thank you!
However I'm trying to redirect the URLs containing a space also like the following:

`https://www.google.com/Articles/Rob's Recommendations.html`

`(\x20)`

This should detect the space but instead I'm getting this:

`Flags should be surrounded by square brackets.`

Comment: @Fernando No problem! (\ ) represents a space (it's escaped with the slash and enclosed in parentheses), and * means 0+ occurrences of it. Try `RewriteRule ^/?Articles/Rob(')s(\ )*Recommendations.html looking-for-something/ [L,NC,R=301]` These tests show that one line working for URLs both with and without spaces at that one point: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=e0fa6df3-dbba-5049-a110-06ce2dfd55c7 https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=e3d5c2dd-75bd-53aa-916b-5e14cb41eda2

Comment: That worked too :)
When you say 0+ occurrences of it..what other options are? Can you for example indicate if there are for example only 4 spaces to process the rule?
Is there any documentation where I can learn more about these rules? I have checked several tutorials but they are too complex and not easily to understand as your explanations.

Comment: @Fernando If you replace the * (zero or more times) with ?, then it would match the space either zero or one time. If you replace it with +, then it would match one or more times. These characters here are "Regular expression (regex) quantifiers." You can also use an integer in brackets to match an exact count. {4} would be exactly four matches of the preceding sequence. Here's a source with some more info on Regex quantifiers: https://javascript.info/regexp-quantifiers